# Django UpdateView: define fields dynamically via function instead of a member variable

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

I have a really simple UpdateView, where my fields are defined by the member variable `fields`

```
class DataUpdateView(generic.edit.UpdateView):
    template_name = 'data/edit.html'
    model = Data
    fields = ['title', 'text']
    text2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('data:index')
```

Now I have the situation that I want to change the fields value depending on a special user permission, but I have no idea how I can define the fields via a function (or any better option).

Is that possible with Django (I'm using the latest version)

Greetings
Tonka

Answer (score 4):

Surely you can. This is a regular class-based view, wich means you should be able to override its methods like `get` and `post` and modify fields there.

In this case you want to set fields on all type of requests, so adding `dispatch` method should be the right choice:

```
class DataUpdateView(generic.edit.UpdateView):
    template_name = 'data/edit.html'
    model = Data
    fields = ['title', 'text']
    text2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('data:index')

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Check permissions for the request.user here
        self.fields = ['title', 'text', 'extrafield']
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Works great. I will check out Daniel's approach too.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the class attributes used in class based views cash be set in equivalently named methods instead. In this case, you can define `get_fields()`.

Comment: Cool. I will check that out tomorrow.

Comment: I don't think this works for generic views (@tonka let me know if I'm wrong). It does work for admin views and rest_framework serializers. Might be worth of a ticket, what do you think?